# Setting a global limit on column length in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm quite new to Postgres (Oracle Background). I wish to prevent people attempting to store JSON, XML, Binary files, etc in a single column in Postgres (This is to avoid TOAST).

The issue is that in the past, developers have attempted to store 100's of millions of lines of XML in our Databases and we've only caught the issue after it's happened. Everything ends up going out to TOAST (Or Lob Objects in the case of Oracle) and performance suffers, along with the storage footprint.

I want to set an absolute limit on the length a column can be.
So for example no TEXT or VARCHAR, and allowing CHARACTER VARYING(n), VARCHAR(n) where "n" is a max of say 500 characters.

In Oracle I'd just create global trigger on create table where schema not in SYS (or default/system schemas) and return and exception on CLOB, BLOB, XML type.

Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

I'm assuming that if the postgres database was called foo that I could just create a trigger on tables in that DB

In the past we have tested some JSON storage add-ons for postgres but they do not do enough. Realistically developers need to embrace the relational model if using a RDBMS to store data.

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: In a single database you could create a trigger that does the check. But if someone can create a new database using a template that doesn't have this trigger, or is able to disable this trigger, you're back to square one. By the way, I don't fully agree with you about XML or JSON ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that come to mind:

1. Create an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that fires on `ddl_​command_​end`, and if the created table is not right, throw an error.
2. The soft solution that does not enforce the rule, but helps people that cooperate: define a domain `string` over `varchar(1000)` and use that everywhere.